# apple mach-o linker error, showing after xcode 4 -> 5 upgrade

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to fix the errors below, they started coming up after I updated to XCode 5. Any idea how to resolve this error. I've looked in the Build Settings - Library Search Paths and its not listed there.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName", referenced from:
      -[DDGameKitHelper registerForLocalPlayerAuthChange] in DDGameKitHelper.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GKAchievementViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DDGameKitHelper.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GKNotificationBanner", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GKAchievementHandler.o
      objc-class-ref in GKAchievementNotification.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GKLeaderboardViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DDGameKitHelper.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GKAchievementDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DDGameKitHelper.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GKAchievement", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DDGameKitHelper.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GKAchievementNotification, _OBJC_CLASS_$_GKAchievementHandler )
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GKScore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DDGameKitHelper.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GKLeaderboard", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DDGameKitHelper.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GKLocalPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DDGameKitHelper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Are you using a library that doesn't contain objects for all of the architectures you're targeting?

Comment: @CarlNorum I am using DDGameKitHelp to pass achievements and scores over. It worked in iOS6 with xcode 4.3 building it.

Comment: It looks like you need to link against GameKit.

Comment: To be clear, I meant [this GameKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008303). (That's Apple's GameKit, not the Ogre version which is apparently something different.)

Comment: Targeting GameKit is needed for iOS 6.0+ but not 5.1